# Syntax error: unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Tags: php, git, laravel, laravel-5.4

There is a project in a bitbucket repository where I am developing with 3 more other people. We have the development branch where we close versions and it is the main branch of the project. The thing is that in my computer all files pulled from that branch works fine and I can navigate trough all pages without getting any exception. On the other hand the other 3 people are getting this error in some pages:

[image]

[image]

Like I said, in my computer this page and some other ones work fine so my guess is that's most likely an error in a file that has .gitignore or individual computer file.

Already tried:

- running composer update, composer dump-autoload, php artisan optimize;
- clearing cache;
- searching into real syntax error in controller (didn't find anything. If there really was this syntax error i'd be getting it too because files are pulled from git);
- deleting logic inside controllers to check if it was syntax error (didn't find anything again);
- replacing their *vendor* folder with my *vendor* folder;
- cloning the project again in their machines

These exceptions occur mainly in namespaces after ***/admin/editar_paginas/vantagens***
We are using AdminLTE package, not sure if there is something related with it.

Honestly I have no ideia what's going on. How can it work specifically in my computer and on theirs not? Let me know if it's not clear enough.

Comment: Did you check your php versions, there where some updates concerning function chaining in php7.

Comment: The error is likely in the blade template, not in the controller.... look in `/app/storage/framework/views` for files with those names

Comment: @ju_ Will check that. But we have been developing for a few months and never had an issue like this.

Comment: What does the code on line 15 look like?

Comment: @MarkBaker Like I said my blade template is exactly like theirs so it's definitly not this.

Comment: @Scuzzy I have no ideia what file is that :/ There is no project file with that name.

Comment: the naming convention looks like a temp file, does it exist on the server during runtime?

Comment: there are a few files in temp folder

Comment: So, have you tried to find that file in the very first place?

Comment: @zerkms That exactly file does not exist in my computer. But I opened all of the temp files and searched for a '->' occurrance and didn't get results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: @ju_ That was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was really PHP version. They had PHP 5.6 in their machines. Upgrading it to ^7.0 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

yesterday i got stuck on a similar situation where i was not getting what the error was all about, so what i did was i deleted the controller,model ,request and migration and recreated it all it removed the error. it worked for me and if there is not much data in the database you could give it a try, laravel does produce such errors from time to time.